# GAE and Highwinds FTP Server

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, ftp

I'm running a GAE python application with 3 modules, one module run every half an hour and is in charge of fetching a file form an FTP server, processing it and saving it to CloudStorage.

Recently the communication between my application and the FTP server start failing more often, increasingly until it became unusable.

The FTP server is Highwinds, they did some changes recently, asked me some questions like the ping and traceroute from the instance running the code to their server, but I'm not able to provide that given the GAE restrictions.

I was able to overcome some errors by just repeating the same operation multiple times.

I'm including some error traces at the end of this message.

I would appreciate some help troubleshooting this issue.

```
  files = ftp_service.nlst()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 509, in nlst
    self.retrlines(cmd, files.append)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 432, in retrlines
    conn = self.transfercmd(cmd)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 371, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 330, in ntransfercmd
    conn = socket.create_connection((host, port), self.timeout)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 569, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

---

```
  ftp_service.retrbinary("RETR %s" % file_path, callback=handle_binary)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 409, in retrbinary
    conn = self.transfercmd(cmd, rest)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 371, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 334, in ntransfercmd
    resp = self.sendcmd(cmd)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 244, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 217, in getresp
    raise error_temp, resp
error_temp: 425 Rejected data connection from foreign address 74.125.183.23:53274.
```

Comment: I'd 1st try to repro while running the app code on the (local) development server - if the issue is reproducible then all info requested by Highwinds to debug the FTP service is obtainable since GAE is effectively out of the loop.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this error locally, it only happened while running on GAE.

After much investigation, it turns out that HW made a security update that started rejecting packets that didn't matched the IP that initiated the connection. On the other side of things, GAE uses multiple IPs when connecting and downloading a file via FTP.